# Cocos3d rotate model

Tags: ios, rotation, cocos3d

guys,I want to rotate an model in cocos3d by touching. I know I should add some code in "-(void) touchEvent: (uint) touchType at: (CGPoint) touchPoint" method but I don't know the detail code. Would anybody give me some detail code or an example about it?Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `CC3DemoMashUp` demo app. It contains lots of examples of interacting with (even rotating) objects using touches and gestures. The `CC3Demo3DTiles` demo app also contains an example of rotating a node with a swipe.